# n-digit primes given the first m digits

Tags: code-golf, primes

I just discovered this site and this is my first question, I hope I'm doing it correctly.

The challenge is the following, you must write a code that prints all the prime numbers of \$n\$ digits. Since this problem is computationally complicated, I think that one way to simplify it is to give a number \$m\$ that will be the first digits of the primes to be printed and let's take \$n\in[1,2,...,10]\$ (there are 45086079 10-digit primes [OEIS A006879](https://oeis.org/A006879)). To reduce problems that the primes of large digits (10,9,8) can generate, we can say that if \$n=10,9,8,7\$ then \$\#m\geq 3\$, where \$\#m\$ denotes the number of digits in \$m\$.

**EXAMPLE**

```
input:
n=4
m=22

output:
2203 2207 2213 2221 2237 2239 2243 2251 2267 2269 2273 2281 2287 2293 2297
```

**RULES**

- You can use built-in functions to generate prime numbers.
- The user must provide \$m\$ and \$n\$.
- Lowest number of bytes in each language wins.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! Id' suggest using the standard [sequence] rules (first `m`, `m`th term or all terms) instead. For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/66833) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take it into account.  If there is any modification to my question, I would like to know.

Comment: I guess that \$m\ge3\$ actually means that \$m\$ would have at least 3 digits?

Comment: @Arnauld yes!!!

Comment: It's a bit confusing that \$m\$ is both used for the input as for the length of the input.

Comment: @Ivo you are right, I have modified the original question, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 10):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [bsdgames package](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/bsdgames/primes.6.en.html), 39

```bash
primes 1 $[10**$2]|grep ^$1|egrep .{$2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoMze1WMFQQSXa0EBLS8Uotia9KLVAIU7FsCYVzNKrVjGq/f//v5HRfxMA)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 65 bytes

```r
\(n,m,k=10^(n-nchar(m)))for(i in 0:k+m*k)sum(!i%%2:i)<2&&print(i)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3HWM08nRydbJtDQ3iNPJ085IzEos0cjU1NdPyizQyFTLzFAyssrVztbI1i0tzNRQzVVWNrDI1bYzU1AqKMvNKNDI1IQZtS9Mw0TEy0uRK0zDUMQdRRjqGxlDJBQsgNAA)

Comment: Doesn't seem to output anything for inputs where \$n\$ is equal to the length of \$m\$ and \$m\$ is a prime (e.g. \$n=2,m=13\$ or \$n=1,m=7\$).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks for spotting. Correction implemented at no byte cost.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
↵:₀/ṡ~æ'⁰øp
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLihrU64oKAL+G5oX7DpifigbDDuHAiLCIiLCI0XG4yMiJd)

Takes `n` then `m`. Prints the primes in order from largest to smallest.

### Explained

```
↵:₀/ṡ~æ'⁰øp
↵:₀/         # 10 ** n, 10 ** (n - 1)
    ṡ        # range(^, ^)
     ~æ      # filtered to only include primes
       '⁰øp  # and filtered to only keep numbers which start with m
```

Comment: [11](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnnAn4oGww7hwOydMwrk9IiwiIiwiNFxuMjIiXQ==)

Comment: @emanresuA I originally had that, but I don't know if it's allowed because it technically never terminates

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
Lε↵~*~+ṡ~æ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJMzrXihrV+Kn4r4bmhfsOmIiwiIiwiMjJcbjQiXQ==)

```
  ↵        # 10 **
 ε         # Digit count minus
L          # Length of starting digits
   ~*      # Multiply by starting digits (without popping)
     ~+    # Add to starting digits (without popping)
       ṡ   # Range from ^^ to ^
        ~æ # Filter by isprime
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
≔Ｘχ⁻ＮＬηθＩΦ⁺…⁰θ×Ｎθ∧›ι¹⬤…²ι﹪ιλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzLCsIwEEX3/YosJxChDe66KoIiWCniD8Q2tIHpxOahnx8Tcefs5tx77rgoN1qFKXXem5lgsG/toKkF6w1FD2d6xnCN6yNTLthF0xwWWDjPz8bbanCGAhyUD3A0GHJrwKzdFM0a6tIR7G5W/be0lYWOJjg5rYpnBGsKQvzZUjCTQW@niLbEyL/XprSvpEy7F34A) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `n` as the first input and `m` as the second. Explanation:

```
≔Ｘχ⁻ＮＬηθ
```

Subtract the number of digits in `m` from `n` and then take `10` to that power.

```
ＩΦ⁺…⁰θ×Ｎθ∧›ι¹⬤…²ι﹪ιλ
```

Take the range from `0` to that number, add on `m` multiplied by that number, then output only the prime numbers in that range.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (v2), 10 bytes

```
⟨{~l}a₀⟩ṗ≜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9icmFjaHlsb2cy/@KGsOKCgeG2oP/in6h7fmx9YeKCgOKfqeG5l@KJnP//WzQsMjJd/1o)

A generator solution that generates all possible outputs (the TIO header converts the generator to a list for printing, but [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753) is that the generator on its own is sufficient to output a list). Input is a list `[n,m]`.

This should be 8 bytes, but I had to add grouping characters `{}` to work around a bug in Brachylog's parser.

### Explanation

```
⟨{~l}a₀⟩ṗ≜
  ~          Checking values whose
   l           length
⟨              is the first input, and
     a₀        which have a prefix that is
       ⟩       the second input,
        ṗ    using only the values that are prime numbers,
         ≜   generate all specific values that meet these criteria.
```

The `{` and `}` don't do anything but are required to prevent the parser crashing.

One interesting quirk of Brachylog: the `l` doesn't imply anything about us looking for *numbers* here, and will also try 4-element lists, but a few of the later restrictions restrict the program to looking for numbers specifically and thus it'll discount 4-element lists as a possibility.

Brachylog's primality testing algorithm is slow but general – it'll work in theory for any number of digits and any size of prefix, but may take a long time on larger numbers.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <strike>83</strike> <strike>80</strike> 75 bytes

```python
lambda n,m:primerange(x:=m*(y:=10**(n-len(str(m)))),x+y)
from sympy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3vXMSc5NSEhXydHKtCooyc1OLEvPSUzUqrGxztTQqrWwNDbS0NPJ0c1LzNIpLijRyNYFAp0K7UpMrrSg_V6G4MregUiEztyC_qEQLYuT2PFsTrlxbIyMuoHl5JRpaaRpAwzU1IbILFkBoAA)

-3 bytes by changing list(x) to [*x]

-5 bytes thanks to [@emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a)

Comment: You're allowed to return iterators, which includes sympy's prime range.

Comment: Also, [75 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3vXMSc5NSEhXydHKtCooyc1OLEvPSUzUqrGxztTQqrWwNDbS0NPJ0c1LzNIpLijRyNYFAp0K7UpMrrSg_V6G4MregUiEztyC_qEQLYuT2PFsTrlxbIyMuoHl5JRpaaRpAwzU1IbILFkBoAA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms I'd expect [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) do the welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 78 bytes

Expects `(n)(m)`, with `m` passed as a string.

```javascript
n=>m=>{for(q=1;!m[n-1];q*=10)m+=0;for(;q--;m++)for(x=m;x-2||print(m),m%--x;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcpBCsIwEIXhvafQgpAxDjRpF8IwvYi4KEKhwtQmlhKwnj0mdJfl@97/6tf@8/TjvOB6iwPHiTvh7ju8vXJs6CT3Cc2D3IVNDaK5pnyRQyTRGvIILBTQbtvsx2lRAlc5IwYC@sVBGVBVUwEd9xfosFtBNpEtrElmCmtzl8L4Bw)

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>              // outer function taking n
m => {            // inner function taking m
  for(            // initialization loop:
    q = 1;        //   q = size of range, initialized to 1
    !m[n - 1];    //   stop when m is large enough
    q *= 10       //   at each iteration, multiply q by 10
  ) m += 0;       //   and append a trailing 0 to m
  for(            // main outer loop:
    ;             //
    q--;          //   stop when q = 0 / decrement it afterwards
    m++           //   increment m after each iteration
  )               //
    for(          //   main inner loop:
      x = m;      //     stat with x = m
      x - 2 ||    //     if we've reached x = 2 without breaking:
        print(m), //       m is prime --> print it
      m % --x;    //     decrement x and stop if it's a divisor of m
    );            //
}                 //
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 117 bytes

```
.+$
$*#
((.)+)¶(?<-2>#)+
$1
+%1`#
0$'¶$`1$'¶$`2$'¶$`3$'¶$`4$'¶$`5$'¶$`6$'¶$`7$'¶$`8$'¶$`9
.+
$*
A`^1?$|^(11+)\1+$
%`1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc09CoAwDEDhPddoxNZgMbX@gSjeQ6QODi4O4ui5PIAXq0Kmb3vv3K79WGO0hICZAq2tIfM@euxzNyhDgAyUcFBQYPo@GFhwQil4oRJqoRFaoQP7xzKYwsIj3otmJjPz/00Cx@gc@A8) Takes `m` as the first input and `n` as the second. Explanation:

```
.+$
$*#
```

Convert `n` to unary.

```
((.)+)¶(?<-2>#)+
$1
```

Decrement `n` for each digit of `m`.

```
+%1`#
0$'¶$`1$'¶$`2$'¶$`3$'¶$`4$'¶$`5$'¶$`6$'¶$`7$'¶$`8$'¶$`9
```

Extend `m` to be `n` digits long, a digit at a time.

```
.+
$*
```

Convert all the values to unary.

```
A`^1?$|^(11+)\1+$
```

Discard `0`, `1` and all composite numbers. (If `n` was always at least `2`, the `^1?$|` would not be needed for a saving of 5 bytes.)

```
%`1
```

Convert the remaining primes back to decimal.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with `-lgmp`, <s>159</s> 147 bytes

- -2 thanks to ceilingcat
- -10 by removing the `#import`

Takes a number length and prefix (as a string).

Luckily GMP has a "next prime number" function, so I just had to turn the prime numbers into strings and compare the prefix to the stringified values.

```c
*t,p[9];f(m,w,u,v)int*w;{u=strlen(w);__gmpz_init(p);for(v=0;v<=m;(v=__gmp_asprintf(&t,"%Zd",p))==m&!strncmp(w,t,u)&&puts(t))__gmpz_nextprime(p,p);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LczRCoIwFMbx@57ChOQcOUJIN7H2IkWITCcDN4ceNRJfvTWiuw8@fn9VdEqFkDP5x/UpNFhaaaYFjeN8FdssJx771sGKoqo669@VcYbBo9DDCIs8i@UmrYjrd1f15MdoNWRM6enepOQRpbTZMYacsh5WYpoxy/zMEzDiP@vaF0dqW/CRiD3ESmJr42AZTIPJdkgSDRdKyzJFcdjDR@m@7qZQ9NF/AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
°DT÷Ÿʒp}ʒ²Å?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9vc2FiaWX//8KwRFTDt8W4ypJwfcqSwrLDhT///zQKMjI)

Port of lyxal's Vyxal answer. It can probably be a bit shorter, but I can't get it to work with just 1 filter.

**Explanation:**

```python
°DT÷Ÿʒp}ʒ²Å?  # Implicit input, with n first then m
°             # 10 ** n
 DT÷          # 10 ** (n - 1)
    Ÿ         # Range between them
     ʒp}      # Primes only
        ʒ     # Keep only those
          Å?  # which start with
         ²    # the second input, m
              # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 17 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 13.99 bytes

```
10@D10,s:gNkgz1ZV
```

(No ATO link since that's on an older version)

Port of lyxal's Vyxal answer.

##### Explanation

```python
10@D10,s:gNkgz1ZV  # Implicit input, with n first then m
10@                # 10 ** n
   D10,            # 10 ** (n - 1)
       s:          # Range between them
         gNk       # Primes only
            g      # Keep only those
               ZV  # which start with
             z1    # the second input, m
                   # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
°ÅP¹ùʒIÅ?
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0IbDrQGHdh7eeWqS5@FW@///TbiMjAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
°          # Push 10 to the power of the first (implicit) input-integer `n`
 ÅP        # Pop and push a list of all primes lower than (or equal to) that 10**n
   ¹ù      # Only keep the primes with a length equal to the first input `n`
     ʒ     # Filter it further by keeping those:
      IÅ?  #  That start with the second input-integer `m`
           # (after which the filtered list of primes is output implicitly as result)
```

---

If we could assume that \$n>L_m\$, where \$L_m\$ is the length of \$m\$, it could be 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) instead:

```python
°Ý«¹ùʒp
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9vc2FiaWX//8Kww53Cq8K5w7nKknD//zQKMjI)

Without that assumption, it would still be 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) with this approach:

```python
°Ý«Iš¹ùʒp
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//8Kww53Cq0nFocK5w7nKknD//zIKMTM)

**Explanation:**

```python
°          # Push 10 to the power of the first (implicit) input-integer `n`
 Ý         # Pop and push a list in the range [0,10**n]
  «        # Append each to the second (implicit) input-integer `m`
   ¹ù      # Only keep the integers with a length equal to the first input `n`
     ʒ     # Filter it further by keeping those:
      p    #  That are primes
           # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly as result)

   Iš      # (prepend the second input-integer `m` to the list; if the length of `m` is
           # equal to `n`, the final result will be `[m]` iff `m` is a prime, or an
           # empty list otherwise)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 105 bytes

```python
lambda n,m:[p for p in primerange(10**n+1)if n==len(d:=str(p))and(s:=str(m))<=d<s+'~']
from sympy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Jc2xDcIwEAXQPlNcF18SJBJRoCieBCiMHIOl3NmynSINi9BEQjACu7ANkVx9_f-L9_z4Jd0dry8jz-85md3xZydFV62AG-pPHowL4MEy-GBpDIpvo2j3VcV1i9YASzmNLHQvYwrCIyrWIuZGiIPUQ6zLR3kpTHAEcSG_gCXvQqoy-N0geWi6rtgETsKIbUDM57rm_AM)